# QGIS Georeferencer problem

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, georeferencing, error

I have a problem with the georeferencer. When I try to georeference a satellite image with no coordinates I get a very high dx,dy and residual values. I use Google Satellite as a base map. The settings I use are in the photos. I believe it has something to do with the projection but I cannot fix it.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can i recommed trimming the image where you won't have any GCPs (ie: The coean/sea) and then jus tkeeping adding GCP's until your residuals are at an acceptable level.

Comment: still same nothing change

Comment: I just replicated your workflow, and unfortunately I can't get the same error. I even took a screen capture of your image and georeferenced it. worked fine. QGIS 3.15. My only other though is maybe your image has a coord system applied to it? Make its coord system is 'invalid projection'. Otherwise maybe try another QGIS installation?

Comment: @nr_aus Thanks for the reply. Still same issue I dont understend why.